# How to set VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "*" } in startup.cs as globally?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I using .net core 5 and needed help where i want to set VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "*" } at startup.cs for all request globally. how can i do it. I know it can be done by attribute at controller like this..
[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jRVf.png)

but i need here at startup.cs
[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1PY2.png)

Answer (score 2):

> I using .net core 5 and needed help where i want to set VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "*" } at startup.cs for all request globally.

You can custom a middleware in Configure method like below:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseResponseCaching();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
        new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };
    var responseCachingFeature = context.Features.Get<IResponseCachingFeature>();
    if (responseCachingFeature != null)
    {
        responseCachingFeature.VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "QueryKeyName" };
    }

    await next();
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

});
```